# Por que no se me cierran las Ventanas JFrame

Tags: java, netbeans, clase, jframe, metodos

Como puedo hacer para que cuando se abra la primera clase (Formulario Ventas) al darle al **`botón buscar`** se abra una nueva ventana (Mostrar Clientes). Formulario ventas no estará visible y cuando le de al **`boton Volver`** se elimine la ventana de la clase Mostrar Clientes y se vuelva a mostrara la clase principal Formulario Ventas.

Lo que me sale ahora es que cuando le doy a los botones `buscar` o `volver` me crean diferentes ventanas. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

**Clase SwingUtils**

```
MostrarClientes mostrarCliente;
FormularioVentasOrdenadores formulario;

public void abrirVentanaMostrarCliente() {
        mostrarCliente = new MostrarClientes();
        formulario = new FormularioVentasOrdenadores();
        mostrarCliente.setVisible(true);
        formulario.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void abrirVentanaFormulario() {
        mostrarCliente = new MostrarClientes();
        formulario = new FormularioVentasOrdenadores();
        mostrarCliente.dispose();
        formulario.setVisible(true);
    }
```

**Clase Formulario Ventas**

```
private void btnBuscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        swingUtilidades.abrirVentanaMostrarCliente();
    }
```

**Clase Mostrar Clientes**

```
private void btnVolverActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
      swingUtils.abrirVentanaFormulario();
    }
```

Comment: Hola Rosa, si tu respuesta te funciona, marcala como aceptada, es difícil saber los requerimientos del programa, por lo de **volver**, tiendo a pensar que no deberías volver a instanciar ***FormularioVentasOrdenadores***, para lo que bastaría con instanciarlo fuera de los métodos mostrados. Si estoy equivocado, tu solución es correcta.

Comment: Si, no la he marcado por que Stackoverflow no me deja, para poder marcarla debe pasar 2 días.

Comment: Disculpame Rosa, no sabía que esto era así.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabo de encontrar una forma para que me salga lo que quiero, no se si es la correcta pero es la que me ha funcionado.

Lo único que he cambiado es el lugar donde usaba el `dispose()` y el `setVisible()`, para que me funcionen los he llamado en la misma clase que quiero que los ejecute.

**Clase Swing Utils**

```
MostrarClientes mostrarCliente;
FormularioVentasOrdenadores formulario; 

public void abrirVentanaMostrarCliente() {
            mostrarCliente = new MostrarClientes();
            mostrarCliente.setVisible(true);
           
        }
    
        public void abrirVentanaFormulario() {
            formulario = new FormularioVentasOrdenadores();
            formulario.setVisible(true);
        }
```

**Clase Formulario Ventas**

```
private void btnBuscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        setVisible(false);
        swingUtilidades.abrirVentanaMostrarCliente();
    }
```

**Clase Mostrar Clientes**

```
private void btnVolverActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        dispose();
        swingUtils.abrirVentanaFormulario();

    }
```